# Remove header (first row) from csv export

Tags: woocommerce

The company I work for has bought the amazing plugin "WooCommerce Customer/Order CSV Export" which really works like a charm. The documentation is sublime, I got my extra fields and I get the snippets to customize my export, this all works perfectly!

Now, I have a small problem with the headers. I need to remove them and I found a filter to apply but I don't understand how to make a function out of this. Can you maybe provide me a way to export the data without the headers on the first row?

So basicly, can you help me write a function that removes the first row of the export or hide the header array?

This is the filter I found in the documentation:
apply_filters( 'wc_customer_order_csv_export_generated_csv', $csv, $this );

Many thanks in advance and with kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//delete headers 
function delete_headers_csv($csv){

    foreach (explode("\n", $csv) as $line) {
      if ($i != 0 ) {
        $temp .= $line."\n";
      }
      $i++;
    }
    echo $temp;
}

add_filter( 'wc_customer_order_csv_export_generated_csv','delete_headers_csv');
```

Comment: THNX MAN YOU ARE THE BEST DEVELOPER!! MUCH THANKSIS, SO HELPED OUTSIS! #DOGE

Comment: honestly - `return array_slice(explode("\n", $csv, 2),-1)[0]` ; without splitting every line and then joining them again ...  (you could also do `$tmp = explode("\n", $csv, 2); return end($tmp);`)